# Running protractor tests from an API call in angular 2+

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, protractor, api-design

I'm using Angular 8 and protractor and I've created a suite of tests that run inside my docker container.

Currently they are executed when the container is run, then the container shuts down.

I would like to change this so that the container can be running and I execute a curl statement from our build server, calling a component inside the project, which in turn, runs the tests and returns the results (or perhaps outputs a report)

I'm great at building tests, but not as good at knowing how to hook a component to call a test.
How would I go about running my suite of tests inside a component?

Comment: Good and useful question. But I feel like its too broad and should be broken into several subtasks

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I am sure you are correct.  I'm not quite knowledgeable enough to break it down however.  At its heart, i want to just know how to declare and call a protractor test in a controller, or at least if that is possible.

Comment: I have a feeling the solution to this question will involve using the node [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) functionality. I have written node programs in the past which trigger protractor in this way. [Example](https://imgur.com/a/UrIhg26). However I not triggered them via user input.